# view swf in asp.net website and determine if it was viewed

Tags: c#, asp.net, actionscript-3, flash

I have a request to host a swf file in an asp.net web page.  That works using an object tag.  My problem is that I need to determine if the user viewed the entire swf file or part of it.  I do not see any events in the HTML object tag that are related to reaching end of the file.

Is there a way to detect that an end of an swf file has been reached in an asp.net web page?

Comment: not really, the swf would have to tell the hosting page.

Answer (score 0):

nope, swf is a relatively closed format, not good for SEO the content inside.

I think there is no way to manipulate inside it by (client or serverside language) without communicating with its actionscript.

so i think you need to use swf source file the .flash source code to add some triggers

(using actionscript 2 or actionscript 3)

to send request to server to do counting when the swf movie enter the lastframe.

BUT

if you convert the flash swf to other relatively open format such as mp4 etc, you can easily adquire the playing progress of it. using html5 video tag or framework such as video.js

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use HTML5.  This website uses frames.  I have been told to not make major changes.

Comment: I created the SWF file from a powerpoint file.  I do not have a .flash source code file.  How can I create one?

Comment: The website uses Javascript ASP pages.  <Frame> and <Frameset> tags are used.  I do not see any DOCTYPE declarations in the ASP pages.  If I get approval, I would make the site html 5 by changing the frame and frameset tags to iframe.  Using the W3C validation site would help.  Are any other free tools available to convert sites to HTML5?

Comment: sorry for the late reply,@Edward Reverse engineering can used on re-convert from swf format to .flash format. ( i did this for many times, if the script author hasn't encrypt the as code, normal flash reverse engineering tools are esay enough to crack it to .flash format then you can add action script and do re-compile using adobe flash IDE.

Comment: I am a novice with Flash SWF files.  I need more information to attempt this task.  Are you using Adobe Flash Professional to make these changes?  When you state .flash format, are you talking about creating a .FLA file?

Comment: @Edward it's not as difficult as you may think to build a swf file from FLA (Adobe Flash IDE) , especially when you already had a swf file, you can import swf to one track and work on.  Moreover, if you have tried using softwares such as swf decompiler (swf-> fla) wouldn't be difficult . if you insist on using flash format,these are the two ways .